# Bootstrap 3 columns order after breakpoint

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="red col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="green col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="blue col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

It is possible to make column orders after breakpoint like this?

[image]

Comment: hi, can you show us what you have done/

Comment: Please define your `html breakpoint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to re-order your divs so that you desinged the layout with the smaller version first, and then using the pull and push CSS classes, move things around. This would work:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="red col-lg-4 col-md-6">r</div>
   <div class="blue col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-md-6">b</div>
   <div class="green col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4 col-md-12">g</div>
</div>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/PoPR2lTeY1)**

And depending on how low you want to go, you could extend the above to:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="red col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">r</div>
   <div class="blue col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">b</div>
   <div class="green col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">g</div>
</div>
```

to get the same layout on the smallest screens.

Comment: @VeeeneX - Um, mine works and yours doesn't? No really, at large sizes your example is RGB (good), but below that it becomes RG/B and the OP wants RB/G.

Comment: Who cares about colors :D?

Answer (score -1):

Try this you need to know your breakpoint

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="red col-sm-6 col-lg-4">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="green col-sm-6 col-lg-4">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="blue col-sm-12 col-lg-4">AAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
</div>
```

This code will 'broke' at 750px width of container.
Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7cP2Y/